# how is possible set background image in ubuntu server with openbox?

Tags: server, 23.10

I'm using Ubuntu Server 23.10 with Openbox and Nitrogen. I've created a folder at `/usr/share/backgrounds` and placed a `.jpg` file inside it. I've set the folder's permissions to 755 with Stefano as the owner and the root group.

However, when I open Nitrogen and attempt to add the folder, the files inside remain unclickable, preventing me from adding them. Does anyone have an idea about what might be causing this issue? Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Ubuntu 23?  Do you mean Ubuntu 23.04 Server ? or Ubuntu 23.10 Server? as they are different releases.

Comment: 23.10 the last version

Comment: Please amend your question to say so.

Answer (score 0):

What window manager? Nitrogen doesn't work with all. Try feh.

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/feh.1.html